# How to iterate through a list to grab values in an transition function in haskell?

Tags: haskell, dfa

I am tasked with defining a (minimal) DFA in haskell. It is in the form ([states], "language", transition function, start state, [accept states]), and is supposed to take in an integer, and create a DFA for it for binary numbers that are divisible by that number. For example, function 4 will create a DFA for binary numbers that are divisible by 4.

I started off with creating DFAs for 1 to 6 to kind of see the pattern that it is taking, and I have figured out that if it is in a state and receives a 0, the binary number is doubled, so it means the state is doubled, and if it receives a 1, the state is doubled and added with a 1.

Here is an example of one I made for all numbers divisible by 4.

```
create 4
  = ([0,1,2,3], "01", ts, 0, [0])
    where
      ts = [ ((0, '0'), 0)
           , ((0, '1'), 1)
           , ((1, '0'), 2)
           , ((1, '1'), 3)
           , ((2, '0'), 0)
           , ((2, '1'), 1)
           , ((3, '0'), 2)
           , ((3, '1'), 3)
           ]
```

Here is the start of my generalised DFA creator which accepts an integer n.

```
create n
  = ([0..(n-1)], "01", ts, 0, [0])
    where
      ts = [ ((x, '0'), x `mod` n)
           , ((x, '1'), (x*2 + 1) `mod` n)
           ] 
        #where x is an iterated number through the states array
```

I am not sure if this is the best or correct way to do it..

I essentially want it to iterate through the states array, and for each state, create 2 transition functions one for if it receives '0', and one for if it receives '1', and apply the logic above.

I am new to haskell, so am not really sure how to approach this. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: list comprehensions are a sort of loop. So, you can write

```
ts =
    [ {- this part is your job -}
    | x <- [0..n-1]
    , char <- ['0', '1']
    ]
```

and this will be a sort of nested loop that iterates through all numbers in the `0` to `n-1` range, and through all of the binary digits. In the `{- this part is your job -}` spot, you can use the names `x` and `char` for the current values of the two loops, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I just have a follow up question. So I got it iterating properly with your loop like so: `[((x, char), x `mod` (n + digitToInt char)) | x <- [0..n-1], char <- ['0', '1']] ` however on the ones where the char is '1', its going to the state n, when in reality I want it to go to state 0 in that case. Is there a way to add some sort of if statement where if the state is n, then its actually 0?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out, didn't realise you can do 'if' statements within lists in haskell :)